# Dynamically broadcast a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

I currently have a 1D numpy array, `epsilons`, that needs to perform element-wise multiplication on array `x`. However, the dimensionality of `x` is dynamic and changes with each iteration of the following for loop:

```
for x in grads:
  x = x * epsilons
  print(grad)
```

`epsilons` always has the shape `(M,)`. However, for the first iteration, `x` takes the shape `(M,4,2)` while it takes the shape `(M,4)` for the second iteration (the shape of x changes as the code iterates over `grads`). Is there a way I can automatically broadcast `epsilons` to the shape of `x` so that I can perform this element-wise multiplication for any shape of `x`?

Comment: First I assume you mean grad = x * epsilons, no?

Second, are you sure that your grads are (M, 4) and not (4, M)?  If they are the former I get a "Value Error: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (M, 4) (M,).  If they are the latter, then one can do the x * epsilon and get the expected result if x.shape is (4, M) or (2, 4, M), or any (..., M).

Comment: Can you change `x` to be (4,2,M) or (4,M) shaped?  Remember the last dimension is inner most, so it makes most sense in numpy to add (or remove) leading dimensions.

Comment: You may want to look into making the `x` dimensions more consistent.  Growing or shrinking arrays in a loop can be costly, and contribute to errors.

Comment: Yeah, true. Unfortunately, the nature of my project requires me to loop through the parameter.grad attributes of a pytorch neural network and modify them. These parameter.grad attributes vary in shape and size, explaining the nature of my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can just reshape `epsilons` to the correct shape. Indeed, Numpy automatically broadcast the vector shape (like the `broadcast_to` call) if is has a **compatible shape**: the same number of dimension should be at least the same and the shape should be either 1 of full for each dimension.
Thanks to @hpaulj for the improved solution.

```py
# Reshape epsilons so that the vector value are along the first dimension (the least contiguous one)
reshapedEpsilons = epsilons.reshape((M,)+(1,)*(x.ndim-1))

# Broadcast automatically the vector values in the other dimensions so the result have the same shape than x
# Actual element-wise multiplication
x *= reshapedEpsilons
```

PS: note that `a = a * b` should create a new matrix and is less efficient than `a *= b` which modify the values in-place.

Comment: I don't think you need the `broadcast_to` step.

Comment: `reshapedEpsilons = epsilons.reshape((M,)+(1,)*(x.ndim-1))`  is an alternative

Comment: @hpaulj Indeed. Thank you. I edited the post to improve it.

Comment: Thanks guys, this solved it! I new epsilons needed to be reshaped, just wasn't sure what needed to be passed to .reshape() to do this properly!